# Web API 2: Added a new controller, it won't register?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

Having a heck of a time here... (Web API 2.1, .NET 4.5.1)

I had one controller that worked perfectly:

```
[RoutePrefix("v1/members")]
public class MembersController : ApiController
{
    [Route("{id}")]
    public Member Get(string id)
    {
        DataGateway g = new DataGateway();

        return g.GetMember(id);
    }
}
```

Works as intended and desired like:

`/v1/members/12345`

But I **added a new controller today and it doesn't seem to be registered or recognized at all**. It doesn't get added to the Help pages and it returns a 404 Not Found when trying to access it:

```
[RoutePrefix("v1/test")]
public class Test : ApiController
{
    [Route("{id}")]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }
}
```

Like I stated, the new controller doesn't show up in the Help pages and returns a 404:

`/v1/test/12345`

[image: Screenshot]

What am I doing wrong?

**EDITED TO ADD:**

I installed tracing and it doesn't even seem to be hitting that.  The first controller works fine and shows a trace, the new Test controller doesn't show any trace info.

**EDIT 2:**

Updated example code to better match my actual code, which was the problem all along.

Comment: Have tou tried putting a constraint on the route? (`[Route("{id:int}")]`)

Comment: The ID needs to accept strings (don't ask) but I will try that for testing purposes. For what reason did you suggest it?

Comment: Because the `id` parameter is an integer. (I was talking about your second route, not the first one)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was here:

```
[RoutePrefix("v1/test")]
public class Test : ApiController
```

Changed to:

```
[RoutePrefix("v1/test")]
public class TestController : ApiController
```

Seems the almighty important word "Controller" needs to be in the class name for the magic to happen.

Comment: Just to add some background here, Web API and MVC are convention-based, so folder and class naming become very important. For example, in MVC, *TestController* also needs a *Views/Test* folder to contain your Razor files, and behind the scenes, .NET will automatically know they go together. In both Web API and MVC, controllers need to be named correctly (i.e. MyThingController instead of MyThing) so the site will know how to apply the routes.